# Movie Clips is working before it is added to DisplayList?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have to add a list of objects into an Array so I can access them Later, but for some reason the object I have added plays before, I add them on to the display list. here is the code:

the Frame Where the list is Added:

```
sunny.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sunny_choice);

function sunny_choice(E:MouseEvent)
{
    var sunny_walkcycle: Sunny_Walkcycle = new Sunny_Walkcycle ();
    var sunny_busstop : Sunny_BusStop = new Sunny_BusStop ();
    var sunny_opening: Teacher_Opening_Sunny = new Teacher_Opening_Sunny ();


    clothingArray.push( sunny_walkcycle);
    clothingArray.push( sunny_busstop);
    clothingArray.push( sunny_opening);

    trace("Sunny");
    cleaner();
//cleaner just removes the event listener and asks it to go to the next frame
}
```

Th next Frame:

```
clothingArray [0].scaleX = -1;

addChild (clothingArray [0]);
clothingArray[0].x = 633;
clothingArray[0].y = 174;
clothingArray [0].stop ();
clothingArray [0].addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, transforming);


function transforming (e:MouseEvent) {
    if (clothingArray [0].currentFrame == clothingArray [0].totalFrames) {
        clearall2 ();

    }
    else{
    clothingArray  [0].nextFrame();
    moving_background.nextFrame ();
    }

}
function clearall2 () {
    clothingArray [0].removeEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, transforming);
    removeChild (clothingArray [0]);

    gotoAndStop (3);
}
```

The problematic One:

```
addChild (clothingArray [1]);
clothingArray[1].addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME , busstop);
trace ("The Current Frame is " + clothingArray [1].currentFrame);
function busstop (d:Event) {
        if (clothingArray [1].currentFrame == clothingArray  [1].totalFrames) {
        clearall3 ();

    }
}

function clearall3 () {
    removeChild (clothingArray [1]);
    clothingArray[1].removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME , busstop);

    }
```

So what Exactly it does is the movieclip in Frame 3 starts playing before it's even added to the Display list and i am not sure what is causing it...I cannot separately add the variable at this frame because there are other options in frame 1 that leads to me making an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Sunny_Walkcycle, Sunny_BusStop, Teacher_Opening_Sunny are MovieClip, why don't you use stop() directly after the memory allocation ?

```
  var sunny_walkcycle:Sunny_Walkcycle = new Sunny_Walkcycle ();
  var sunny_busstop:Sunny_BusStop = new Sunny_BusStop ();
  var sunny_opening:Teacher_Opening_Sunny = new Teacher_Opening_Sunny ();

  sunny_walkcycle.stop();
  sunny_busstop.stop();
  sunny_opening.stop();
```

Be sure there is no code in your MovieClip inner frames that will mess with your control code.
Like a play()... hidden somewhere.

You could also try (for sunny_busstop), just after pushing in the array :

```
clothingArray[1].stop();
```

or

```
clothingArray[1].gotoAndStop(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a MovieClip will start playing once it is created. It doesn't need to be added to the Display List to be activated. This is very important detail to understand.

The Display List only determines whether or not a Display Object is connected to the stage hierarchy.

solution... call the `stop()` method after creation and then the `play()` method when you add them to the Display List.

If you don't call the `stop()` method when removing from the Display List, it'll just keep on eating up cpu cycles. If you have numerous MovieClips with tweens etc, that can be quite significant.